# Flutter: global key's context is null in some elements from the list

Tags: flutter

I am creating a listView and I assign to each card a unique global key, so that I can use `getCardWidth` in order to get the width of a card. The problem is that the current context is null except for the first 3 containers.

```
ListView.builder(
              controller: _controller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final key = getKey(index);
                return Container(
                  key: key,
                  child: CategoryCard(category: categories[index], onClick: (){
                    print("Clicked $index");
                    setState(() {
                      selected = index;
                    });
                    centerItem(context, index);
                  }),
                );
              },
            ),
```

```
getCardWidth(){
      RenderBox renderBox = getKey(index).currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      return renderBox.size.width;
}
```

Comment: Do only 3 containers appear on screen? They way I understand ListView is that it will render a minimal set of items depending on what is viewable, so if the other containers don't appear on screen, then it's likely they the key hasn't been assigned to a widget.